# consulta de transact sql a linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Tengo una consulta en `Transact SQL`, y la necesito modificar a `LinQ` para una migración de un programa que estoy haciendo, pero he tenido problemas específicamente con una función de `SQL Server`, el `datediff`, con la que me ha sido dificultoso realizarla en `LinQ`.

```
SELECT        AVG(Diario) AS Expr1
FROM            (SELECT        SUM(VolumenTanqueo) AS Diario
             FROM            EQ_Tanqueo
             GROUP BY FechaTanqueo
             HAVING         (DATEDIFF(dd, FechaTanqueo, GETDATE()) <= 100))
     AS derivedt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para implementar el `DateDiff` en linq debes implementar

[SqlFunctions.DateDiff Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datediff(v=vs.110).aspx)

esto convertira el linq a sql

Comment: Pero no puedo implementar el datediff de SqlFunctions.DateDiff Method, entonces no se si se pueda implementar por otro método.

Comment: porque no puedes usar el SqlFunctions, hay alguna razon ? la verdad que otra forma no conozco que exista ya que necesitas que la implementacion se pueda convertir de linq a sql

Comment: Pues estoy referenciando desde (using system.data.sqlclient), pero no aparece, no se si es otro espacio de nombres, o es por la verison del entity framework, yo estoy trabajando con la 4.0.

Comment: la version .net 4 deberia tener esta funcionalidad, pero el namespace deberia ser System.Data.Objects.SqlClient

Comment: si, definitivamente esa función me sirvió, y le agradezco de verdad, pero ahora me sale una excepción. the specified type member 'date' is not supported in linq to entities. 
creo que es por el tipo de valor date, y he averiguado como trabajar con ese tipo de datos, o por lo menos castearlo, pero siguen saliendo excepciones.